# How to put a column of picture names to the csv file of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, opencv

This is my first question here so I'm sorry If I'm doing this wrong.

I have a folder with pictures in it that I turned into arrays and put in a csv file using Python 3. It works fine but I want to add the name of the picture as a row in the beginning of the csv file. If it would help, I also have the pictures in seperate files(like labels) and I could also loop through the seperate folders and add the name of the folder as a row in the left side of the csv file but I do need all the arrays to be in the same csv file at the end. How can I do this? Here is the code I used to turn the images into the array and save into a csv file:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

IMG_DIR = '../train'

for img in os.listdir(IMG_DIR):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_DIR,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        if img_array is not None:
            img_array = (img_array.flatten())
        img_array  = img_array.reshape(-1, 1).T
        with open('train.csv', 'ab') as f:
            np.savetxt(f, img_array, delimiter=",")
        print(img_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer (producing csv file containing the `filename, pixel_value_array` per line)

```
with open("train2.csv", "w") as f:
    for img_name in os.listdir(IMG_DIR):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, img_name), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        f.write(img_name + ",")
        np.savetxt(f, img_array.reshape((1, -1)), delimiter=",")
```

Original answer: Write all the filenames first and then append the array data.

```
images = os.listdir(IMG_DIR)
with open("train.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(images) + "\n")
for img in images:
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_array = img_array.reshape(-1, 1).T
    with open("train.csv", "ab") as f:
        np.savetxt(f, img_array, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This does add rows with the names of the files but the rest of the column is empty and doesn't match with the arrays :(

Comment: Please explain more clearly how you want the csv file to look. Do you want it to like this maybe? `filename1.png, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, ... \n filename2.png, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0 ... \EOF

Comment: Exactly! I want the first row to be the name of the file and the rest of the rows to be the arrays from that image.